# How to encode data for showing xml in php?

Tags: php, xml

I am generating XML dynamically. There may be arbitrary data which is entered by users. Which characters do I have to encode in order to show them properly in the XML file?

I am using PHP.

Comment: `<>'"&` are the 'Big 5'. `htmlspecialchars()` will do this for you automatically.

Comment: You need ENT_QUOTES as well to encode the `'`'s. Otherwise it just encode's `<>"&`

Comment: htmlspecialchars('asfa<>sf') shows me asfa<>sf. No encoding. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: echo htmlspecialchars("asfa<>sf", ENT_QUOTES); gived me asfa<>sf.  Is it encoded?

Comment: @elbek htmlspecialchars encodes those characters so that they look the same as they were meant to in a browser, but don't function the same in XML or HTML. it encodes `<` as `&lt;` for example, and a web browser renders `&lt;` as `<` w ithout it having the meaning it does in XML